# Is that true that if we reduce the Cl in water will reduce the saltiness of water?

Tags: water

I just move to some place near the ocean and I dig a weld and the water taste is a little bit salty (not as salty as sea water but there are salty taste). Then, I bring the water to the lab and there are 2 points that are really high the TDS $3345\,\mathrm{mg/litre}$, and $\ce{Cl-}$ $998\,\mathrm{mg/litre}$.

I already use a softener to reduce the $\ce{CaCO3}$ and magnesium content, and now my water treatment guy that install the first softener suggest me to add another filter that contain resin and can absorb $\ce{Cl-}$ content, he said to me The resin will absorb the $\ce{Cl-}$ content and make the water taste better. He also said that it will need $\ce{HCl}$ or $\ce{(NH4)2 SO4}$ to regenerate the resin.

My question is:

**1.** Is that true that we can reduce the saltiness in water if we remove the $\ce{Cl-}$ ?

**2.** What kind of resin this water treatment guy talking about? Is this resin even exist?

Comment: In short: 1. True. 2. That's an [ion exchange resin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion-exchange_resin); yes, it exists.

Comment: In order to remove $\ce{Cl- }$, you need at least an _anion_ exchange resin (or a mixed-bed ion exchanger, which, however, cannot be easily regenerated). Used anion exchange resin (that is loaded with $\ce{Cl- }$) cannot be regenerated with $\ce{HCl}$. $\ce{HCl}$ can be used to regenerate _cation_ exchange resins.

Comment: @Loong can you suggest which chemical that need to regenerate anion exchange resin? This conclude that the water guy give me wrong resin.